# full calendar - exibir dados

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Estou tendo problemas para exibir uma informação. Segue o código:

Aqui é onde deveria exibí-la:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email do cliente</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="varchar" maxlenght="80" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail do cliente" />
  </div>
</div>
```

O email é registrado através de um formulário e está tudo dando certo (relacionado a salvar no banco de dados e fazer outras alterações), o problema é que quando quero detalhar o evento essa informação não aparece.

```
    eventClick: function (info) {
        info.jsEvent.preventDefault(); // don't let the browser navigate
        console.log(info.event);
        $('#visualizar #id').text(info.event.id);
        $('#visualizar #id').val(info.event.id);
        $('#visualizar #title').text(info.event.title);
        $('#visualizar #title').val(info.event.title);
        $('#visualizar #start').text(info.event.start.toLocaleString());
        $('#visualizar #start').val(info.event.start.toLocaleString());
        $('#visualizar #end').text(info.event.end.toLocaleString());
        $('#visualizar #end').val(info.event.end.toLocaleString());
        $('#visualizar #cliente').text(info.event.extendedProps.cliente);
        $('#visualizar #cliente').val( info.event.extendedProps.cliente);
        $('#visualizar #email').text(info.event.extendedProps.email);
        $('#visualizar #email').val( info.event.extendedProps.email);**
        $('#visualizar #endereco').text(info.event.extendedProps.endereco);
        $('#visualizar #endereco').val( info.event.extendedProps.endereco);
        $('#visualizar').modal('show');
    },
```

Os outros dados como nome, endereço que também são registrados pelo formulário estão sendo exibidos normalmente.